# How can I calculate settings for manual flash to reduce trial and error?

Tags: flash, exposure, metering, calculations, manual-flash

I have two Yongnuo 560-III flashes that I have been using for a while, In order to get good results I am having to do a lot of trial and error. Adjusting power, zoom, moving them around etc.

Is there anyway that I can calculate more accurately what settings I should put into them, maybe based on the in camera metering?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the guide number system (see [How can I calculate the effect of non-TTL flash on exposure?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29930/how-can-i-calculate-the-effect-of-non-ttl-flash-on-exposure)), possibly in combination with your camera's meter or a separate incident flash meter. But if you have several lights, modifiers, and are trying different poses and positions, **trial and error is probably actually easier and faster**. As you practice, it'll tilt more towards "trial" and less towards error. This is a huge advantage of digital — in the film days, studio photographers used Polaroids, but now every camera has that built-in.

Comment: That's a very helpful post, with alot of useful information, sorry I didn't see it before posting. Thanks.

Comment: @Edward144 You're welcome. I added a little additional information here because you elaborate a little more about your more-complicated use, and I wanted to get in the note about trial and error not actually being so bad.