# Nikon flash guide number

Tags: flash, film, mamiya, guide-number

I have recently purchased a Nikon SB-28 flash for my Mamiya 645 1000s camera. Since I can use the flash only in the Manual mode, I am trying to create a guide in order to be able to calculate the distance that I can use my flash for. For my camera, I have an 80mm lens and most of the time I am using 400 ISO film. Regarding the aperture, I prefer from 11-22 F-stop normally. Now I found that the guide number of the flash is:

> Guide number (ISO 100, m): 36 (with zoom headset at 35mm)

Since I am not familiar exactly with the term, how can I calculate the distance for my case? Any ideas? Is anyone familiar with any mobile application maybe that can do this automatically?

Comment: See this related question: [How do I set exposure with a manual flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/29930/11924)

Comment: But how can I make the conversion from 100 to 400 ISO and the zoom?

Comment: How can we answer the question if you don’t correctly specify the model number of the flash? Is it an SB-28 or SB-29?

Comment: Hmm, ops I was so sure that I wrote it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the GN is 36 (meters) at ISO 100, it is x2 or GN 72 at ISO 400  (meters).

Specificaly  new GN = old GN x square root(new ISO / old ISO)

Guide Number = distance x f/stop Number.  This takes the Inverse Square Law into account.

So at GN 72 and f/16, direct flash exposure is GN 72 / f16 = 4.5 meters.

Or the other way for example, GN 72 / 8 meters is f/9.

This applies only to the same flash head zoom that the original GN 36 was for.

The flash manuals have a GN chart that shows GN for other zoom values, but I don't think the SB-29 zooms?  See http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/NikonF5/Flash/SB29/index.htm for much detail about the SB-29. It says GN 36 is feet, meters is GN 11.  GN meters is GN feet / 3.28, so ISO 400 would be GN 22 meters.

My web site has a GN calculator and much more GN information at http://www.scantips.com/lights/flashbasics1c.html   which might be useful.

Comment: My flash is sb-28, not sb-29. There is one option for zoom.  There is one zoom button to the flash, I guess you refer to that, right?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mir.com.my%2Frb%2Fphotography%2Fhardwares%2Fclassics%2FNikonF5%2FSB28Manual%2Findex.htm&psig=AOvVaw1IC1bcAsBeT_OqGbQ8_J6b&ust=1589221692740000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJjzvKb2qekCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE

Comment: You previously said SB-29, but yes, the SB-28 does zoom.  Its GN chart is on its manual page 56, and is  GN 30/98 (meters/feet) for ISO 100 at zoom 24 mm zoom ...  to GN 50/164 at 85 mm zoom.  Double those for ISO 400.  A confusion is that it can also do HSS which is a very different GN on page 51 (but HSS requires a compatible HSS camera).

Comment: The SB-28 manual is at https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/Speedlights/SB-28.pdf

Comment: How can we answer the question if you don’t correctly specify the model number of the flash? Is it an SB-28 or SB-29?

Comment: It is true but anyway the answer of @WayneF even if meant to be for sb-29 I can consider that it answers all vague points since it covers an explanation for all cases not for a specific model. The most important for me to understand the way that by knowing the guide number I can calculate the distance and not just how to do that for a specific model.